# Merge Pandas Dataframes based on substring or partial match in another Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have two sample data frames:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Model': ['0RW52HC5KDD13R', '0RW52HC5KDD13U','JJS42HC5JSSAYR']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Group_Var': ['0RW52HC5K', '0RW52HC5K','JJS42HC5J']})
```

Using this will result result in an empty dataframe.

```
df3 = df1.merge(df2, left_on='Model', right_on='Group_Var')
```

How could I go about using a merge to use a substring / partial match from `df2['Group_Var']` in `df1['Model']`? Perhaps using the `str.contains()` method as part of the merge?

Just for context my expected output would be something like this:

```
Group_Var        Model
0RW52HC5K        0RW52HC5KDD13R
0RW52HC5K        0RW52HC5KDD13U
JJS42HC5J        JJS42HC5JSSAYR
```

Comment: Such a simple answer, will accept as soon as possible, thank you

Comment: Yes, I love when things are so simple too! :)

Comment: Just as a side question, is `concat` method possible if there are multiple columns in both dataframes, but still using the `['Model', 'Group_Var']` as the merging columns?

Comment: Yes. In fact, I believe there can be any number of columns, of any names, and of varying lengths, in either dataframe (or rather, _all_ dataframes because `pd.concat` can take more than 2). `pd.concat` doesn't actually look at the columns - it just annexes them together. So it's not as smart as a merge, but it's what you're looking for here (I believe).

Comment: @user17242583 I think it was just a bad example. OP using `concat` only joins multiple DataFrames side by side (for axis=1) via index alignment. It doesn't do any type of substring match, which is what you seem to want. It only works in this simple case because of the order of the rows of both DataFrames in your example (they are already aligned).  In your real DataFrame, I'm assuming that the rows of each DataFrame can be in any order...

Comment: Perhaps. But the OP accepted...

Comment: @user17242583 Because they are not aware of that most likely... They saw the output in this simple case and assumed it would work in general. I'm just warning OP.

Comment: It's a good point. If it's not what they expect (you probably are right), they can unaccept it and then I'll improve it. :)

Comment: Hi Guys, It was a bad example but the answer certainly worked for it. The indexes were aligned which made `concat` a viable answer. Anyhow, I certainly learnt a few things by exploring `concat`, thanks again

Comment: Okay, great @James. If you do run into an error _later_ down the road, e.g. a week or more later, I think it might be better to ask a new question. Bringing back up old, small questions like this can be a losing battle :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `pd.concat` with `axis=1`:

```py
df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
```

Output:

```py
>>> df3
            Model  Group_Var
0  0RW52HC5KDD13R  0RW52HC5K
1  0RW52HC5KDD13U  0RW52HC5K
2  JJS42HC5JSSAYR  JJS42HC5J
```